# Is the FreeRadius the right thing for me?

Tags: freeradius

I am looking for a solution that will help me to do the following thing:

I want a user to log into my system by using his corporate account. This means I want to use his company's authentication system to verify that this person is the one he says he is and after that I will grant him access to my resources.

The question is if the freeradius project is the right thing for me?

I have read the documentation and didn't correctly understood. I also want some of my users to use their social accounts to log into my system as well.

More background: I am looking for a free alternative of [Auth0](https://auth0.com/)

Comment: This question way too general.  What holds the credentials for the corporate account? Is it Active Directory, Novell, OpenLDAP, Azzure...?

What social media authentication mechanisms, OpenID, Oauth? 

What system are they logging into? What authentication protocol does it use? MSCHAP, CHAR, EAP (which flavour), PAP...

Comment: Well, I am not that educated in that sphere. I want to support companies that use ADFS, LDAP and Google stuff. OAuth 2.0 is going to be the tagret for the social media. About the authentication protocol... I just want a token or whatever to be given after the user authenticates against his company's system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst FreeRADIUS supports authentication against LDAP and Active Directory, it does not support Oauth 2.0 or any other web-based authentication system out of the box.

Support can be added for these backends using one of the dynamic language modules such as rlm_perl or rlm_python, but this will require some development on your side.

FreeRADIUS primarily authenticates users via the RADIUS protocol, it's not a generic drop in for multiple application like Auth0.
That said, there is a RADIUS PAM module, so any application which supports PAM authentication could, in theory, authenticate against FreeRADIUS.  The main issues with this are it doesn't work for authentication methods that require complex iteraction between the end user and the backend authentication directory.

FreeRADIUS, in general, has quite a steep learning curve, and a lot of the documentation already assumes you know how the protocols involved work. You may be better off using a commercial authentication provider until you gain some more experience in application security.